# Change an existing field of value type float to an optional float in a protobuf message

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a message of the following type

```
message Foo {
    string bar = 1;
    float baz = 2;
}
```

Is there any problem in converting it to the following for use in Go ?

```
message Foo {
    string bar = 1;
    optional float baz = 2;
}
```

Is the preferred way to deprecate and create a new field in the proto in this case as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on how deeply integrated that particular message is in your code base - meaning

1. are you storing the marshaled binary representation somewhere like your database
2. are different parts of your code base using different versions of the message you are modifying - e.g. older versions of your android/ios apps and such

point being if you use a message structure to unmarshal encoded data, that was not generated with the very same message structure, into - bad things will happen.

The docs recommend adding a new element to circumvent such scenarios entirely. If that is not something you want to do, take the above points into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The `optional` will make the field a pointer type. So in Go generated code, `optional float` will become `*float32`, which of course is **not** `float32`.

To deprecate a field, use `[deprecated = true]` field option:

```
message Foo {
    string bar = 1;
    float baz = 2 [deprecated = true];
}
```

If in subsequent releases of your protobuf schema you actually remove the field altogether from the message, you might want to add `reserved 2`, where `2` is the number of the field you removed.

```
message Foo {
    string bar = 1;
    reserved 2;
}
```

This helps preventing other people or future you from adding a new field in position 2. This is relevant in case you have outdated clients which still expect a `float` in position 2.

PS: `optional` fieds in Proto3 are supported from version 3.15

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [FloatValue](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#floatvalue) type defined in the [google.protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf) package. As example:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message Foo {
  string bar = 1;
  google.protobuf.FloatValue baz = 2;
}
```

Will generate a pb files with the content:

```
type Foo struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Bar string                 `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=bar,proto3" json:"bar,omitempty"`
    Baz *wrapperspb.FloatValue `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=baz,proto3" json:"baz,omitempty"`
}
```

You can use as follow:

```
  f := Foo{
      Bar:           "Bar",
      Baz:           &wrapperspb.FloatValue{Value: float32(3)},
  }

  var floatValue float32 
  if f.Baz != nil {
      floatValue = f.Baz.GetValue()
  }
```